# To open a partial view as popup from mvcSiteMapNode in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an partial view and I want to open on click of the MVC site map node

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Add New Page" controller="Horizon" action="PView"></mvcSiteMapNode>
```

I am using button and on click on that button it will show the pop up window, instead I want to open on click of the site map node

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divpopup').dialog({ autoOpen: false });

    $("#btnAddNew").click(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("_AddNewView","Horizon")';
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#divAddnew").html(data);
            $("#divAddnew").dialog('open');
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you try so far?

Comment: Please take another stab at that question. `MvcSiteMapProvider` is primarily a server-side technology. JavaScript is a client-side technology. At this point I fail to see how you are tying them together. Do note, that you can edit the HTML that is output to the client by `MvcSiteMapProvider` by editing the views in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder.

Comment: How to do that from DisplayTemplates? . Can you give me an idea of how to do that?